DynamoDB single partition transactions
I am new to DynamoDB transactions. The documentation says that

These actions can target up to 100 distinct items in one or more DynamoDB tables within the same AWS account and in the same Region.

which is great.
However, I'm curious about performance implications of using transactions. Here it is shown that transactions in DynamoDB might be up to 4x slower than plain PutItem. The performance penalty is not a surprise to me because I assume that DynamoDB's transactions coordinator needs to implement some kind of 2PC . On the other hand, in case ALL items that are affected by the transaction are stored in the same partition the coordinator does not need to do the second round of 2PC protocol when committing such transactions. This is covered here in the end of Section 4.
I'm wondering if anyone has any data on performance implications of single partition transactions in DynamoDB?
